# Accidentally overlapped the Gnome and Unity interfaces. Now they are causing my menues to glitch badly. Help!

Tags: interface

Okay. So I am a supernoob to linux and consiquently Ubuntu (Version 10.10). I saw that I could use the synaptics manager to download the Unity interface. I didn't realize that when i went to install and apply Unity that it would not automatically unistall Gnome. Now everything is glitching within the Gnome/Unity interface and I am clueless as to how to remove either one of them. Help!!!

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Synaptic.
2. On the bottom left, click the Status button.
3. Above that, choose Installed. Now you should see a list of all your installed packages.
4. Find the unity package.
5. Right click on it, select Mark for Complete Removal.
6. Apply your changes.
7. If it doesn't fix things right away, either restart X, or just reboot altogether.